# Is there a reason the command 'mongo' works in VSCode terminal but not iTerm2 zsh terminal?

Tags: mongodb, visual-studio-code, terminal, iterm2

I just installed oh-my-zsh on iTerm2 and have been working on a project with MongoDB/node.

Now when I try to start the db with command 'mongo' I get a return 'zsh: command not found: mongo'

the command works perfectly fine in the built-in terminal for VSCode.

would like to be able to use iTerm exclusively instead of the vscode terminal.

Comment: Did you check the path?

Comment: trying to learn how to edit the path now, this is my current PATH I checked in vscode terminal `❯ echo "$PATH"
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin
❯ which mongo
/opt/homebrew/bin/mongo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to VSCode terminal and execute:

   ```
   echo "$PATH"
   ```
2. Check where the mongo binary is located:

   ```
   which mongo
   brew info mongo
   ```
3. Go to your zsh and add to your .zshrc file the path where mongo is located:

   ```
   export PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin"
   ```
4. If you do not add the path you will still be able to run it like:

   ```
   /opt/homebrew/bin/mongo
   ```

Comment: Following your steps here is my result. 

`echo "$PATH"
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin
❯ which mongo
/opt/homebrew/bin/mongo
❯ brew info mongo
Error: No available formula with the name "mongo". Did you mean mono, mongosh, mon or monero?
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.`

Comment: oke so it looks your mongo is installed here: /opt/homebrew/bin/mongo  and you need to add the path: /opt/homebrew/bin to your  zsh  resource file .zshrc

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but when I went directly into the .zshrc file and added this line

```
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin"
```

the command 'mongo' still didn't start the db.

BUT..

I figured it out. Instead of opening my .zshrc and editing it I just edited my path with this little line here with the path described by [R2D2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10415047/R2D2)

```
path+=/opt/homebrew/bin/
```

Command 'mongo' is working perfectly now!

Comment: After editing the .zshrc file, you will need to either exit and reopen the shell or run `source ~/.zshrc` for it to take effect.

Comment: Thank you Joe, next time I come across needing to edit my PATH I will try again with another 'export' and then save and reset. I didn't close and restart the shell so that definitely could have been an issue for me.